# Xamarin.Forms - Android Activity with async OnCreate method

Tags: asynchronous, android-activity, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, akavache

I'm running into the questions if it's a problem to mark `FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate(Bundle bundle)` as async? I have to fetch user-specific data from an AWS DynamoDB, and I need to retrieve the user from the Akavache cache before in order to query with the userId. Of course, I could also save the userId to the local settings or serialize the whole user object to be able to retrieve it synchronously.

I also don't expect performance issues during startup because the cache uses SQLite definitely exists. The only problem is that either I await Akavache's `GetObject<T>(string key)` and therefore, mark everything down to `OnCreate` as async, or I subscribe to the returned Observable and the following methods will try to query the user data without a valid userId, because the Observable hasn't returned yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using XF for development, the code `LoadApplication(new App());` in `OnCreate` of `MainActivity` will hook the lifecycle event to `App`'s lifecycle event in PCL.

You didn't post any code, I guess that you place your code for data fetch after `LoadApplication(new App());`, then as you said it didn't return yet, otherwise the behavior should be different.

I suggest you to call your task in the `OnStart()` of `App` in PCL and together use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to call into your async task for fetching data from PCL.

Comment: I implemented different start methods in `App` which I call from `OnCreate` based on the Intent I'm receiving. Because I always have to fetch the user as part of the login process, I needed to call the async method from all start methods and therefore, mark them async as well as `OnCreate`. I haven't thought about just using the `OnStart` method instead and mark it as async. I'll try that - thanks! :)